# jQuery mobile applies to all jade files (Node, Express)

Tags: node.js, express, jquery-mobile

I have a jade file that looks like this:

**home.jade**

```
        html
            head
                title= title
                link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
                link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css')
                script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')
                script(src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js')
            body
                block content
                ...

                li
                    a(href='/documents', class='text-center') Add Document
```

It includes jquery mobile css and js. When I follow a link from **home.jade** to any other jade file, it automatically picks jquery mobile scripts even though they are not inculuded in the other jade files.

For example, when I click on "Add documents" link it leads me to **documents.jade** that looks like this:

**documents.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        body
        ...
```

But when I inspect element it has jquery mobile classes attached:

```
<html class="ui-mobile">
```

When I refresh a page only then the mobile classes disappear.
Anybody knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how I managed to do it (not the most elegant way but it works..)

in **home.jade** I've put this in the head section:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
});
```

and in all other jade files I've put this after the body tag:

```
script.
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function(event){
        $('.ui-link').removeClass('ui-link');
    });
```

and I've put this line of code in all the places I don't want jquery mobile to take effect:

```
(data-enhance="false")
```